# Getting correct data when using multiple deferred ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function that uses two ajax calls in order to get the proper information:

```
var getUsers = function() {
  return $.getJSON("http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/EAIJj.js", function(foo) {
    return $.getJSON("http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/EAIJj.js", function(bar) {
      return foo['age'] = bar.type;
    });
  });
}
```

And an outside function that calls the current function and only continues when the calls are finished.

```
getUsers().then(function(result) {
  // ...
});
```

Now the weird thing is that if I display the result, the 'age' will show up in the console, but if I try to access it using `result['age']`, it will return undefined.

Is there a proper way of handling multiple deferred calls?

### Code

http://codepen.io/norbiu/pen/bNRQxL

Comment: You are calling `result['age']` before it is set, when first request succeed. The console.debug() works by reference. You can see it using e.g`console.debug(JSON.stringify(result));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** Instead of using a separate deferred, you can chain the ones returned from `getJSON()` like this

```
var getUsers = function() {
  var foo;
  return $.getJSON("http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/EAIJj.js")
  .then(function(data) {
      foo = data;
      return $.getJSON("http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/EAIJj.js")
  }).then(function(bar) {
      foo['age'] = bar.type;
      return foo;
  });
}
```

Note: you need to save the return value from the first call or it won't be accessible to the second.

**Original code for posterity**

You can use a jQuery Deferred object and return that instead

```
var getUsers = function() {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();
  $.getJSON("http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/EAIJj.js")
  .done(function(foo) {
    $.getJSON("http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/EAIJj.js")
    .done(function(bar) {
      foo['age'] = bar.type;
      dfd.resolve(foo);
    }).fail(function(e) {
       dfd.reject(e);
    })
  }).fail(function(e) {
      dfd.reject(e);
  });
  return dfd.promise();
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvwqZo

The deferred object won't resolve until both requests succeed (and will fail if any of them fail).

Comment: no need for an extra `deferred`. `$.ajax` returns a deffered itself. A lot of people call this an anti-pattern for ajax

Comment: @charlietfl How would you that here? Because you want the deferred to be resolved/rejected only once the nested request completed